# Weird char in python module

Tags: python

In the package for Python 2.7.4, when you go to `Lib -> email -> errors.py`, there is something funny in the module.

---

```
# Copyright (C) 2001-2006 Python Software Foundation
# Author: Barry Warsaw
# Contact: email-sig@python.org

"""email package exception classes."""



class MessageError(Exception):
    """Base class for errors in the email package."""


class MessageParseError(MessageError):
    """Base class for message parsing errors."""


class HeaderParseError(MessageParseError):
    """Error while parsing headers."""


class BoundaryError(MessageParseError):
    """Couldn't find terminating boundary."""


class MultipartConversionError(MessageError, TypeError):
    """Conversion to a multipart is prohibited."""


class CharsetError(MessageError):
    """An illegal charset was given."""



# These are parsing defects which the parser was able to work around.
class MessageDefect:
    """Base class for a message defect."""

    def __init__(self, line=None):
        self.line = line

class NoBoundaryInMultipartDefect(MessageDefect):
    """A message claimed to be a multipart but had no boundary parameter."""

class StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(MessageDefect):
    """The claimed start boundary was never found."""

class FirstHeaderLineIsContinuationDefect(MessageDefect):
    """A message had a continuation line as its first header line."""

class MisplacedEnvelopeHeaderDefect(MessageDefect):
    """A 'Unix-from' header was found in the middle of a header block."""

class MalformedHeaderDefect(MessageDefect):
    """Found a header that was missing a colon, or was otherwise malformed."""

class MultipartInvariantViolationDefect(MessageDefect):
    """A message claimed to be a multipart but no subparts were found."""
```

---

This is the entire content of the module. Apart from this, there are 2 very strange characters which don't show up in the preview, and can't be copy-pasted.
They look like stick-characters of humans (in notepad), and I found it pretty amusing.

One of them is in the line before

```
class MessageError(Exception):
    """Base class for errors in the email package."""
```

The other is after

```
class CharsetError(MessageError):
    """An illegal charset was given."""
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what these characters are doing there? Or is it just my package?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't be copy-pasted"?  Can you not select them?  Does pasting them produce an empty box?  An empty space?  Perhaps a screenshot would also be helpful.

Comment: @ASGM, I can select, but when I paste, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opening this file in Vim shows a `^L` character, a.k.a [form feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break).

If you refer to [PEP8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id13), you'll find:

> Python accepts the control-L (i.e. `^L`) form feed character as whitespace; **Many tools treat these characters as page separators, so you may use them to separate pages of related sections of your file**. Note, some editors and web-based code viewers may not recognize control-L as a form feed and will show another glyph in its place.

In your case, these `^L` simply logically separate `MessageError` derived classes from `MessageDefect` derived classes.

Comment: Page separator? Oh my... "Pages"? Is that an ancient technical term from back when we stored information in slices of dead trees?

Answer (score 1):

They're there in my version of the package too. Opening the file with a binary editor I see

```
0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0C 0D 0A
```

All those `0D 0A` pairs are carriage return / line feed (Windows line endings). The `0C` is a form feed character, so when the module is printed you get each section on a separate page. Your Python parser should just ignore them.